# java class file constructor of SslSelectChannelConnector.class not being called

Tags: java, jetty, ijetty

I m trying to run [i-jetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/) in eclipse using the m2e (maven) plugin. The source code of file IJettyService.java at line 530 gives makes this call

```
            SslSelectChannelConnector sslConnector = new SslSelectChannelConnector(sslContextFactory);
```

Eclipse IDE here complains

```
The constructor SslSelectChannelConnector(SslContextFactory) is 
 undefined
```

so I used a decompiler and found out that it does exists.

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
public SslSelectChannelConnector()
{
    this(new SslContextFactory(SslContextFactory.DEFAULT_KEYSTORE_PATH));
    setSoLingerTime(30000);
}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------ */
/** Construct with explicit SslContextFactory.
 * The SslContextFactory passed is added via {@link #addBean(Object)} so that 
 * it's lifecycle may be managed with {@link AggregateLifeCycle}.
 * @param sslContextFactory
 */
public SslSelectChannelConnector(SslContextFactory sslContextFactory)
{
    _sslContextFactory = sslContextFactory;
    addBean(_sslContextFactory);
    setUseDirectBuffers(false);
    setSoLingerTime(30000);
}
```

---

I  don't understand why its behaving this way . Did anyone came across similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

from what you posted here this should work. maybe you have an older version of the jetty library on your classpath? try `new SslSelectChannelConnector( null )` and see what happens.